# Button locked to guidelines. Why is position changing with orientation?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Using Xcode 8.3.2 I've placed a button in the center of the portrait oriented iPhone 7 and placed it with horizontal and vertical guidelines. When the orientation is switched to landscape the button is not in the center. How do I force the button layout to stay the same regardless of device/orientation?

Comment: I'd suggest to add some screenshots to make it more clear... Also, I think that it is not related to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints for the button should be 
`Button.CenterX = centerX` 
`Button.CenterY = centerY` 
 
This can be achieved by while holding the "control" clicking(mouse-down) on the button and then move mouse pointer to the superview (ViewController in your case). Once horizontally. And once vertically. And chose
"Center vertically in container" and "center vertically in container" accordingly.

This can be checked if you look at the "left" ViewController Scene navigation panel. There is should be "Constraints" now (under the button). If you don`t have it something was probably missed.